# Configure image asset in Android Studio, next button only vibrates modal

Tags: android, image, android-studio

I can not get past the Next button, the modal just vibrates.  I have tried everything and changed everything.  Even reinstall Android Studio, past versions, and this is happening on my employees Mac too.

[image]